# How to create interactive checkboxes for filtering a DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, interactive, ipywidgets

I am working on a Jupyter Notebook project and I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

**Info**

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 6936 entries, (2199603, 1357456995) to (2200982, 1357808973)
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                          --------------  -----
 0   34                              6936 non-null   int64
 1   36                              6936 non-null   int64
 2   38                              6936 non-null   int64
 3   40                              6936 non-null   int64
 4   42                              6936 non-null   int64
 5   44                              6936 non-null   int64
 6   46                              6936 non-null   int64
 7   48                              6936 non-null   int64
 8   multiple_sizes_in_transaction   6936 non-null   bool 
 9   duplicate_sizes_in_transaction  6936 non-null   bool 
dtypes: bool(2), int64(8)
```

I want to create an interactive filtering mechanism using checkboxes for the columns multiple_sizes_in_transaction and duplicate_sizes_in_transaction. The checkboxes should allow me to filter the DataFrame based on the selected values (True or False).

I tried using the interact function from the ipywidgets library as follows:

**Test Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, Checkbox

# Load the data
df = df

@interact(multiple_sizes=Checkbox(value=False), duplicate_sizes=Checkbox(value=False))
def filter_data(multiple_sizes, duplicate_sizes):
    filtered_df = df[(df['multiple_sizes_in_transaction'] == multiple_sizes) & 
                     (df['duplicate_sizes_in_transaction'] == duplicate_sizes)]
    display(filtered_df)
```

**Test Data**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'USIM': [2199603, 2199603, 2199603, 2199603, 1357459, 1357459, 1357459, 1357459, 2200982, 2200982, 2200982, 2200982, 2200982],
    'WEBSHOP_ORDER': [1357456995, 1357456996, 1357456997, 1357456998, 1357459079, 1357460517, 1357471294, 1357472723, 1357807067, 1357807855, 1357808382, 1357808849, 1357808973],
    '34': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    '36': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '38': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    '40': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '42': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    '44': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    '46': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '48': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'multiple_sizes_in_transaction': [False, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False],
    'duplicate_sizes_in_transaction': [False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the index
df.set_index(['USIM', 'WEBSHOP_ORDER'], inplace=True)

# Display the DataFrame
display(df)
```

**Dataframe**

```
          SIZE         34   36  38  40  42  44  46  48  multiple_sizes_in_transaction   duplicate_sizes_in_transaction
USIM    WEBSHOP_ORDER                                       
2199603 1357456995  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   False   False
        1357456996  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   False   False
        1357456997  0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   True    False
        1357456998  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   False   False
1357459 1357459079  0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   True    False
        1357460517  1   0   2   0   0   0   0   1   True    True
        1357471294  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   True    False
        1357472723  0   0   0   0   0   2   0   1   False   True
2200982 1357807067  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   False   False
        1357807855  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   False   False
        1357808382  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   False   False
        1357808849  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   True    False
        1357808973  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   False   False
```

[image]

However, the checkboxes are not displayed as expected. The output is empty (nothing)
How can I create interactive checkboxes for filtering my DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the Checkbox widget from ipywidgets library does not have a label parameter. Instead, you need to use the description parameter to add a label to the checkbox. Here's the updated code that should display the checkboxes with labels:

```
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, Checkbox

# Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('your_table.csv')

@interact(multiple_sizes=Checkbox(description='Multiple Sizes in Transaction', value=False), 
          duplicate_sizes=Checkbox(description='Duplicate Sizes in Transaction', value=False))
def filter_data(multiple_sizes, duplicate_sizes):
    filtered_df = df[(df['multiple_sizes_in_transaction'] == multiple_sizes) & 
                     (df['duplicate_sizes_in_transaction'] == duplicate_sizes)]
    display(filtered_df)
```

In the updated code, I added the description parameter to each Checkbox widget to display a label for the checkbox. You can customize the label text to suit your needs.

Also, make sure that the path to your data file is correct and that it is loaded correctly into the DataFrame. The DataFrame must have the columns multiple_sizes_in_transaction and duplicate_sizes_in_transaction for the filtering to work.

Comment: unfortunately no, there is still no output, maybe the issue i with multiple index?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) framework to make interactive DataFrame with checkboxes. Mercury offers a [Checkbox](https://runmercury.com/docs/input-widgets/checkbox/) widget. Its usage is much simpler than in ipywidgets because there are no callbacks. You just define the widget. Mercury can serve notebook as web app and cells below the checkbox will be automatically re-executed after change.

Please notice that there is no automatic re-execution during the notebook development - only when running notebook as web app. During development you can use widgets, but you need to manually re-execute cells.

Here is an example code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import mercury as mr
```

```py
data = {
    'USIM': [2199603, 2199603, 2199603, 2199603, 1357459, 1357459, 1357459, 1357459, 2200982, 2200982, 2200982, 2200982, 2200982],
    'WEBSHOP_ORDER': [1357456995, 1357456996, 1357456997, 1357456998, 1357459079, 1357460517, 1357471294, 1357472723, 1357807067, 1357807855, 1357808382, 1357808849, 1357808973],
    '34': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    '36': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '38': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    '40': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '42': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    '44': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    '46': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '48': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'multiple_sizes_in_transaction': [False, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False],
    'duplicate_sizes_in_transaction': [False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the index
df.set_index(['USIM', 'WEBSHOP_ORDER'], inplace=True)
```

```py
multiple_sizes = mr.Checkbox(label="Multiple sizes", value=False)
```

```py
duplicate_sizes = mr.Checkbox(label="Duplicate sizes", value=False)
```

```py
df[(df["multiple_sizes_in_transaction"] == multiple_sizes.value) & 
   (df["duplicate_sizes_in_transaction"] == duplicate_sizes.value)]
```

#### Full code in the notebook

[image: Notebook code]

#### Web app from notebook in Mercury

Please start Mercury Server in the same directory as notebook to have web app running:

```bash
mercury run
```

[image: Web app with interactive Pandas DataFrame]

Mercury can be deployed on any machine with Python available. You can use docker-compose for deployment ([docs](https://runmercury.com/docs/docker-compose/)) or [Mercury Cloud](https://cloud.runmercury.com).